# How to fast check list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-2.x

Suppose I have a list as the following:

```
a = ['111', '222', '3334', '12']
```

When I just check a element, over or less 3 length, it will return error and stop to detect.

This is my approach:

```
for b in a:
    if len(b) != 3:
        return False
```

But should it have better method, how to do?

---

It's for discussing performance with `any` and `all`. sureshv mentions `any` is better `all` but I use `timeit` proves `all` is better than `any`. However, `not all(...)` can be ignored, `not` is expensive for performance.

```
from timeit import timeit

print timeit('any(len(x) != 3 for x in ["111", "222", "3334", "12", "111", "222" , "111", "222" , "111", "222"])', number=100000)
print timeit('all(len(b) == 3 for b in ["111", "222", "3334", "12", "111", "222" , "111", "222" , "111", "222"])', number=100000)
print timeit('not all(len(b) == 3 for b in ["111", "222", "3334", "12", "111", "222" , "111", "222" , "111", "222"])', number=100000)

>>>first
0.0830238555881
0.0820391147939
0.0863792158681

>>>second
0.0826572149797
0.0818332714663
0.0830155876428

>>>third
0.0836901379378
0.0809026999688
0.0812479579601
```

Comment: `all(len(b) == 3 for b in a)`

Comment: @PeterWood Great! You should post your answer. Please don't lost your chance.

Comment: any is a better check especially if you have long lists.

Comment: @sureshvv do you mean I have a list containing many elements, I use `any` is better?

Comment: Yes. `any` will return as soon as it fails first. `all` will have to check every element, So if the very first element has length 1, `any` won't check the other elements.

Comment: @sureshvv `any` and `all` will only check what they need. `all(len(b) == 3 ...` will perform the same number of comparisons as `any(len(b) != 3 ...`

Comment: @sureshvv I use `timeit` to compare `any` and `all` when the list is same. `all` is better than `any`.

Comment: @BurgerKing That surprises me. There should be little difference. Can you post the code?

Comment: @PeterWood It's okay. I will post my comparisons.

Comment: @PeterWood Done. I have posted my code, if you think the list is still too short, you may modify the code.

Comment: @BurgerKing I wouldn't say that's a significant difference. The best results are only 2% different.

Comment: @PeterWood Although the best results are only 2% different, when the list is very big, the execution time will be bigger. It can't be ignored.

Comment: @PeterWood Don't you post your answer? Although your answer is in comments, you are still earlier than other people.

Comment: @PeterWood.. You are right. Same number of comparisons for `all` and `any`. Thank you.

Comment: @BurgerKing Your conclusion that `not` is expensive doesn't make sense. The fastest with `not` is faster than the slowest without `not`. The variance in the results is so little, you can't conclude that one is definitely faster than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
if any(len(x) != 3 for x in a):
    return False
```

Comment: Or you could have `if not all(len(x) == 3 for x in a)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use all -

```
def check_element(a):
    return all(len(b) == 3 for b in a)
```

or conventionally using lambda

```
def check_element(a):
    return not bool(list(filter(lambda b: b != 3, a)))
```

Though first approach is much more pythonic, and that is the one you should go for.